# get the value of a cell in a different worksheet by referring the name of the worksheet contains in some other cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to get the value of a cell in a different worksheet by referring the name of the worksheet contains in some other cell. 
For an instance, I have this formula to get the value from a cell from another sheet `='Sheet2'!H25`. But I want to replace the `'Sheet2'` of the formula of a cell contains the text "sheet2".
Cell A25 contains the name of a sheet titled "Sheet2" which I got from the formula `=MID(CELL("filename", A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename", A1))+1,31)`

So, instead of `='Sheet2'!H25` I tried the formula `=INDIRECT("'" A25 & "'!" & H25)` But it doesn't work. How to make it work.

P.S: A25 is in the Sheet1 and H25 is in the sheet2

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to double-quote **H25** .

Either:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & A25 & "'" & "!" & "H25")
```

or

```
=INDIRECT("'" & A25& "'!H25")
```

*(the second equation combines the various parts after the sheet-name)*